# Type Mismatch: cannot convert one type to another

Tags: java, arrays, inheritance

I am following a YouTube tutorial on how to make a simple 2D game on Java and so far I have not encountered any problems until now.

I have created a following array to main `Gamepanel (gp)` class:

```
public Character npc[] = new Character[10];
```

Where `Character` is main class for characters (player, npcs etc). Character class:

```
public class Character {
    
    GamePanel gp;
    public int worldX, worldY;
    public int speed;
    public BufferedImage up1, up2, down1, down2, down3, left1, left2, left3, right1, right2;
    public String direction;
    public int spriteCounter = 0;
    public int spriteNum = 1;
    public Rectangle solidArea = new Rectangle(0, 0, 48, 48);
    public int solidAreaDefaultX, solidAreaDefaultY;
    public boolean collisionOn = false;
    public int actionLockCounter = 0;
    
    public Character(GamePanel gp) {
        this.gp = gp;
    }
```

And I would like to add an npc class called `NPC_OldMan` to the `npc[]` array but it gives me Type Mismatch error: cannot convert from `NPC_OldMan` to `Character` The NPC_OldMan class:

```
package character;
import main.GamePanel;


public class NPC_OldMan extends Character {

    public NPC_OldMan(GamePanel gp) {
        super(gp);
        
        direction = "down";
        speed = 1;
        
        getImage();
    }
```

The tutorial maker in question is not experiencing the similar problem and that makes me frustrated. Have I missed something?

Comment: I'd suggest to change the name of your class. `Character` is already a class in `java.lang`.

Comment: Indeed, it is plausible that the place where you are getting the compilation error does not import *your* `Character` class and is using the standard one (`java.lang.Character`) instead.  That result in that error ...

Comment: Thank you! The problem was was the class name `Character`. I renamed that and now it works.

Comment: @VilleT that wasn't the problem. Had you imported the right one, it would have worked just fine.